# Как сделать замену строки в подстроке игнорируя невидимые символы Java?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, replace, замена

```
String text = "mama mula ramu";
String find = " mu\nl a";
String replace = "bila";
String result = text.replace(find, replace)
```

Как сделать, чтоб результат был String result = "mama bila ramu"?

Comment: пробел тоже надо удалять между `l` и `a` ? или имелось в виду что пробелы тоже все к черту? если пробелы тоже, то что делать, если надо заменить словосочетание? или "привет тебе сосед" на что-то еще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно проверить на https://www.compilejava.net/
На [ideone](http://ideone.com/gOC1OG) почему-то `Внутренняя ошибка`.

```
public class Program
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String text = "mama m ula ramu";
    String find = " mu\nl a";
    String replace = "bila";

    find = find.replaceAll("\\W", "");
    find = find.replaceAll("(?!^)(.)", "\\\\s*$1");
    System.out.println(find);

    String result = text.replaceAll(find, replace);
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо. Только результат тут: `System.out.println(find);` - m\s*u\s*la, а должен быть я предполагаю m\s*u\s*l\s*a. Можете исправить, а то я совсем не дружу с регуляркой)

Comment: @user200303, исправлено.

Answer (score 1):

Пользуемся регуляркой и удаляем предварительно из `find` эти символы (как попарно, так и отдельностоящие). И пробелы также вырезаем.

```
String text = "mama mula ramu";
String find = " mu\nl a";
String replace = "bila";

find = find.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\r\\n)+", "").replaceAll("\\s+","");
// find = find.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\r\\n|\\s)+", "");
String result = text.replace(find, replace);

System.out.println(result);
```

Если пробелы оставить, то, значит часть с `.replaceAll("\\s+","")` (или `\\s` из закомментированного выражения) выбросить.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. А как можно сделать, чтоб оно меняло если в тексте так же есть невидимые символы. Например `String text = "mama mu l a ramu";` или `String text = "mama m u l\na ramu";`

Comment: @user200303 лично для меня таких данных вообще не достаточно. Нужно более подробное и детальное описание,как то 1) что подразумевается под "невидимыми символами" 2) полный список правил замены в исходном тексте. Например из `mama mu l a ramu` во что должно превратиться в `mama bila ramu` или в `mama bi l a ramu` или еще что. Какова вообще логика замены? А если слов больше в исходном тексте, а не данный конкретный шаблон, а если в заменяемом текст больше слов, то как они совпадать должны и определять что нужно заменить именно это слово...без подробностей, для меня - это гадание на кофейной гуще

Comment: 1) Невидимые символы - пробел, перенос строки и табуляция. 2) Заменить надо на точную строку которая указана в `String replace;` 3) И слов для замены может быть много в тексте. `String text = "mama mu la m ula m u l a ramu m/nula"`, а результат будет `mama bila bila bila ramu bila`

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно предварительно убрать все непечатаемые символы из строки

```
str.replaceAll("[\\u0000-\\u001F\\u007F\\u0080-\\u009F]", "");
```